# Display Data in autocomplete text view after DOM parsing

Tags: android

how to display data in autocomplete text view after DOM parsing. am getting data from the webservice but i don't know how to display in the autocomplete textview.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample gotten from [android developer's site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
         protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
             super.onCreate(icicle);
             setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

To put it simple, its similar to a listview but adds in a textview on top or underneath the text. The contents are what is in the array list.